# Click on button, overflow-y of html turns hidden, if click again, it turns back visible

Tags: javascript, click

I'm trying to do this thing: I want that, when clicking on a button, the overflow-y of my html becomes hidden. Then, when clicking again, it turns visible, and so on. So far, I have done this: (the button has id #plus)

```
$('#plus').click(function () {
   $("html").css({
      'overflow-y': 'hidden',
   });
});
```

It works one time only of course. How can I turn it back?

Comment: set `overflow-y` to `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#plus').click(function () {
   var overflowY = 'hidden'; 
   if($("html").css('overflow-y') == 'hidden') overflowY = 'visible';
   $("html").css({ 'overflow-y': overflowY });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus">Change Overflow Y</button>
```